# Bad Product Order on Category Page WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer

I'm first time here, and have one serious problem with my product ordering into product category page. For some reason, instead latest product to align to left, it is aligned by right side. For example:

[bad image aligment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4hLl.png)

That products are generated by Visual Composer shortcode element:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
function jws_theme_products_grid_render($atts) {
global $wp_query;
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'product_cat'           => '',
    'show'                  => 'all_products',
    'number'                => -1,
    'hide_free'             => 0,
    'show_hidden'           => 0,
    'orderby'               => 'none',
    'order'                 => 'none',
    'tpl'                   => 'tpl1',
    'columns'               => 4,
    'show_pagination'       => 0,
    'align_pagination'      => 'text-center',
    'el_class'              => '',
    'show_sale_flash'       => 0,
    'show_title'            => 0,
    'show_price'            => 0,
    'show_rating'           => 0,
    'show_add_to_cart'      => 0,
    'show_quick_view'       => 0,
    'show_whishlist'        => 0,
    'show_compare'          => 0,
    'show_view_more'        => 0
), $atts);
extract( $atts );
$class = array();
$class[] = 'woocommerce tb-products-grid';
$class[] = $tpl;
// if( $tpl == 'tpl2' && $columns > 1){
//     $class[] = 'tb-products-grid';
// }
$class[] = $el_class;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'order'          => $order
);
$query_args['meta_query'] = array();
if ( empty( $show_hidden ) ) {
                $query_args['meta_query'][] = WC()->query- 
>visibility_meta_query();
                $query_args['post_parent']  = 0;
        }
        if ( ! empty( $hide_free ) ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key'     => '_price',
                    'value'   => 0,
                    'compare' => '>',
                    'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
                );
}
$query_args['meta_query'][] = WC()->query->stock_status_meta_query();
$query_args['meta_query']   = array_filter( $query_args['meta_query'] );
if (isset($product_cat) && $product_cat != '') {
    $cats = explode(',', $product_cat);
    $product_cat = array();
    foreach ((array) $cats as $cat) :
    $category[] = trim($cat);
    endforeach;
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                        'terms'         => $category,
                        'field'         => 'slug',
                        'operator'      => 'IN'
                )
    );
     }
     switch ( $show ) {
        case 'featured' :
                $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                'key'   => '_featured',
                                'value' => 'yes'
                        );
                break;
        case 'onsale' :
                $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
                        $product_ids_on_sale[] = 0;
                        $query_args['post__in'] = $product_ids_on_sale;
                break;
        case 'variable' :
                $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_type',
                    'terms'         => 5,
                    'field'         => 'id',
                    'operator'      => 'IN'
                );
                break;
    }
    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'price' :
            $query_args['meta_key'] = '_price';
            $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
            break;
        case 'rand' :
            $query_args['orderby']  = 'rand';
            break;
        case 'selling' :
            $query_args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
            $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
            break;
        case 'rated' :
            $query_args['orderby'] = 'title';
            break;
        default :
            $query_args['orderby']  = 'date';
}
$wpp = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$class_columns = array();
switch ($columns) {
    case 1:
        $class_columns[] = 'tb-product-item tb-woo-one-column col-xs-12 col- 
   sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12';
        break;
    case 2:
        $class_columns[] = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6';
        break;
    case 3:
        $class_columns[] = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4';
        break;
    case 4:
        $class_columns[] = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3';
        break;
    case 5:
        $class_columns[] = "col-lg-20 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12";
        break;
    default:
        $class_columns[] = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3';
        break;
    }
    ob_start(); 
    if ($wpp->have_posts() ) {
    $i = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $class)); ?>">        
    <div class="row<?php if( $columns == 1) { echo ' tb-product- 
   items';}elseif($tpl !='tpl1'){echo ' tb-products-grid';} ?>">
        <?php
            while ($wpp->have_posts() ) {$wpp->the_post();
                if( $i==0 && $tpl=='tpl3' ){ ?>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <?php include $tpl.'.php'; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    $tpl = 'tpl2';
                }else{
                ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', 
    $class_columns)) ?>">
                        <?php include $tpl.'.php'; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <?php if( $show_view_more ): ?>
        <div class="tb-view-more-link"><a data-args='<?php echo json_encode( 
     $query_args );?>' data-atts='<?php echo json_encode( $atts );?>'  
href="#"><span> 
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( $show_pagination && $wpp->max_num_pages > 1 ){ ?>
        <nav class="pagination <?php echo esc_attr( $align_pagination );?>" 
 role="navigation">
            <?php
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( 
 get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
                    'total' =>$wpp->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', 
'organiko' ),
                    'next_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', 
'organiko' ),
                ) );
            ?>
        </nav>
    <?php }
      wp_reset_postdata();
     ?> 
</div>
<?php
}else {
    echo 'Post not found!';
} 
?>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
if(function_exists('insert_shortcode')) { insert_shortcode('products_grid', 
'jws_theme_products_grid_render'); }
```

Into Visual Composer element is not settings for this thing. I tried to use default woocommerce visual composer element, and products are properly aligned to page. So issue is somewhere into this element. This is [example](http://www.bevelini.com/peppers/) where that product is bad showed.